# Excpetion and Cyclic dependency when deploying meteor todo app

Tags: heroku, meteor

I am new to `meteor` and `Heroku` and tried to set up the tutorial todo app from meteor with `Heroku` and `mongoDB` atlas. The app runs perfect on my local machine with local host, when I start it with `meteor`. Now I wanted to deploy it on `Heroku`. So I created a `mongoDB` free account, added a whitelist for all ip addresses, created a database user with read and write permissions on any database. Then I got a connection string which looks like this (I am not sure if that's a correct connection string for meteor):

```
mongodb+srv://DATABASEUSER:PASSWORD@todoauto-ivrrg.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

I choose "Connect Your Application" and selected as driver "Node.js" and version as "3.0 or later".

In the next step I created my `Heroku` free account, downloaded the `CLI` for my terminal, logged in to `Heroku`, created a local git repository, created a new app, added the build pack from "admithub/meteor-horse", set the MONGO_URL to the connection string from MongoDB Atlas and set the ROOT_URL to https://todoauto.herokuapp.com. Then I pushed everything to Heroku.

I am not sure if I need to change or add anything to the Todo app from meteor. When I try to start the app with Heroku, it immediately crashes. I checked the log and thats what I get:

```
2019-04-04T07:24:36.751039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node $NODEJS_PARAMS .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2019-04-04T07:24:40.937843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-04T07:24:40.952903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885782+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885811+00:00 app[web.1]: throw(ex);
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885813+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885815+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885817+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: cyclic dependency detected
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885825+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:331:34)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885827+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885828+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:345:18)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885829+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885831+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:345:18)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885833+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885834+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:345:18)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885836+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885837+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:345:18)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885839+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885840+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:345:18)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885842+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885843+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:345:18)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885844+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885845+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeObject (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:345:18)
2019-04-04T07:24:40.885846+00:00 app[web.1]: at serializeInto (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:934:17)
```

I hope some can help me with my problem, I am pretty new to everything and read many guides how to set up meteor with Heroku and followed every step. I didn't get any error until I tried to start the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when connecting to a MongoDB Atlas database, where the MongoDB server version was 4.0.10 (presumably too new to work with the old example).

Try this fork of the example instead, which uses an updated version of the node mongodb driver:

https://github.com/onezoomin/todos

i.e.:

```
git clone https://github.com/onezoomin/todos
```